# Text going to next line - how to keep on same line?

Tags: formatting, text-manipulation

My cover for my thesis looks like this:

[image: Thesis Cover]

The relevant MWE looks like this (I am using a template)

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
John \textsc{Smith}
% Your name
\href{mailto:john.doe@gmail.com}{john.doe@gmail.com}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Dr. Cornelius \textsc{Van der Westhuizen}% Supervisor's Name
\href{mailto:cornevdw@gmail.com}{cornevdw@gmail.com}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[4cm]
```

How do I move the 'Huizen' part of 'Westhuizen' onto the same line?

Comment: You have to increase the width of the second mini page `\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}`. But note that there is another one before it, so you can take care of the total width.

Comment: this isn't really relevant to the question as asked, but the two lines of the title are very close together, at least partly because there are no descenders in the first line.  it would look nicer if you put a `\strut` somewhere in the first line to remedy that.

Comment: Thanks Sigur! Perfect. Made the first name 0.3 and the second one 0.5.

Answer (score 3):

although an explicit line break (the double backslash) may be needed because the
name of your supervisor is very long, it may be enough just to provide a space
after the name:

```
Dr. Cornelius \textsc{Van der Westhuizen} % Supervisor's Name
\href{mailto:cornevdw@gmail.com}{cornevdw@gmail.com}
```

as you have input it, the `%` that immediately follows the name in braces causes
the `\href{...}` to be tied tightly to the end of the name, with no break.
(it is also not a recognized place for a comma; even if the line were broken there
with a comma, that wouldn't be the desired output.)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should contemplate changing several things:

- As others have already noted, the width of the second minipage simply isn't sufficient to typeset the entire name. Increase the width to something like `0.45\textwidth`.
- Rather than separate the two minipages merely by `~` (a space), I suggest you employ `\hspace{\fill}`. That way, the block with the two names will span the entire width of the text block. (If you think that doing so places the two names too far apart, consider placing both minipages inside a larger minipage environment (of width `0.8\textwidth`, say) which could be center-set.)
- For the sake of symmetry in layout, I would add explicit line breaks both before your email address *and* the supervisor's email address.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}      % set margins to suit your needs
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref} % for \href macro
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} 
\large
\emph{Author:}\\
John \textsc{Smith}\\ % Your name
\href{mailto:john.doe@gmail.com}{john.doe@gmail.com}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} 
\large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Dr.\ Cornelius \textsc{Van der Westhuizen}\\ %Supervisor's Name
\href{mailto:cornevdw@gmail.com}{cornevdw@gmail.com}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very bad quick-fix, the package `\usepackage{mathtools}` is needed. And notice that you're missing a `\\` after their name.

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
John \textsc{Smith}
% Your name
\href{mailto:john.doe@gmail.com}{john.doe@gmail.com}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
\leavevmode\llap{Dr. Cornelius }\textsc{Van der Westhuizen}\\% Supervisor's Name
\href{mailto:cornevdw@gmail.com}{cornevdw@gmail.com}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[4cm]
```

Maybe just adding the missing `\\` would suffice:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
John \textsc{Smith}
% Your name
\href{mailto:john.doe@gmail.com}{john.doe@gmail.com}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Dr. Cornelius \textsc{Van der Westhuizen}\\% Supervisor's Name
\href{mailto:cornevdw@gmail.com}{cornevdw@gmail.com}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[4cm]
```

As well, please post a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) next time.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other answers provided, you could place the name in a box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{flushleft} \large
  \emph{Author:}\\
    John \textsc{Smith}
    % Your name
    \href{mailto:john.doe@gmail.com}{john.doe@gmail.com}
  \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}%%
%%
\hspace*{\fill}%%
%%
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{flushright} \large
    \emph{Supervisor:} \\
    \makebox[1.5in][r]{Dr. Cornelius \textsc{Van der Westhuizen}}\\% Supervisor's Name
    \href{mailto:cornevdw@gmail.com}{cornevdw@gmail.com}
  \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[4cm]


\end{document}
```

Since I don't know what your page set up is (how large the margins are), this may possibly result in an overcrowded appearance.